# How to lag data table value by more than one

Tags: r, data.table

Say I have a data table.  I can create a column of lagged values:

```
>x
date    id   val  valPr
1/4/14   a    1     2
1/3/14   a    2     3 
1/2/14   a    3     4
1/1/14   a    4     NA
1/4/14   b    10    20
1/3/14   b    20    30
1/2/14   b    30    40
1/1/14   b    40    NA
```

Using:

```
setDT(x)[, valPr := c(val[-1], NA), by = "id"]
```

Is there a way to do something similar to lag by more than one period?  Three for example?

It would produce something like this:

```
>x
date    id   val  valPr
1/4/14   a    1     4
1/3/14   a    2     NA 
1/2/14   a    3     NA
1/1/14   a    4     NA
1/4/14   b    10    40
1/3/14   b    20    NA
1/2/14   b    30    NA
1/1/14   b    40    NA
```

Comment: If you use `dplyr` something like this works for you. `x %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(valPr2 = lead(val, 3))`. So, you may want to try something like `setDT(x)[, valPr2 := lead(val, 3), by = "id"]`?

Comment: Or just write a `lead` function - [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24557781/559784). Maybe we should provide lag/lead functions, quite common enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could alternatively do the following. `lead` is a function in `dplyr`.

```
setDT(mydf)[, valPr2 := lead(val, 3), by = "id"]

#     date id val valPr valPr2
#1: 1/4/14  a   1     2      4
#2: 1/3/14  a   2     3     NA
#3: 1/2/14  a   3     4     NA
#4: 1/1/14  a   4    NA     NA
#5: 1/4/14  b  10    20     40
#6: 1/3/14  b  20    30     NA
#7: 1/2/14  b  30    40     NA
#8: 1/1/14  b  40    NA     NA
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(date = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("1/1/14", "1/2/14", "1/3/14", "1/4/14"), class = "factor"), 
id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor"), val = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 20L, 
30L, 40L), valPr = c(2L, 3L, 4L, NA, 20L, 30L, 40L, NA)), .Names = c("date", 
"id", "val", "valPr"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 2):

With `data.table`, you would do it like this:

`nlags = 3 
x[ by="id", 
   , valPr := c( val[ - seq(nlags) ], rep( NA, nlags) )
]`

What this does is replaces the first `nlags` from `val` and then put that number of `NA` values at the end.  You can adjust this to easily put the lagged values at the beginning or end of the series.